# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty}x^4\left(\arctan\frac{2x^2+5}{x^2+1}-\arctan\frac{2x^2+7}{x^2+2}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

> Evaluate $$\lim_{x \to \infty}x^4\left(\arctan\frac{2x^2+5}{x^2+1}-\arctan\frac{2x^2+7}{x^2+2}\right)$$

## My Solution

Denote
$$f(t):=\arctan t.$$
By Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem，we have
$$f\left(\frac{2x^2+5}{x^2+1}\right)-f\left(\frac{2x^2+7}{x^2+2}\right)=f'(\xi)\left(\frac{2x^2+5}{x^2+1}-\frac{2x^2+7}{x^2+2}\right)=\frac{3}{(1+\xi^2)(x^2+1)(x^2+2)}$$
where $$\frac{2x^2+5}{x^2+1}\lessgtr \xi \lessgtr \frac{2x^2+7}{x^2+2}.$$
Here, applying the Squeeze Theorem, it's easy to see$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\xi=2.$$
It follows that
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}x^4\left(\arctan\frac{2x^2+5}{x^2+1}-\arctan\frac{2x^2+7}{x^2+2}\right)=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{3x^4}{(1+\xi^2)(x^2+1)(x^2+2)}=\frac{3}{5}.$$

**Hope to see other solutions.THX.**

Answer (score 5):

Recall that by  [**Arctangent addition formula**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Arctangent_addition_formula)

$$\arctan\dfrac{2x^2+5}{x^2+1}-\arctan\dfrac{2x^2+7}{x^2+2}=\arctan \left(\frac{\dfrac{2x^2+5}{x^2+1}-\dfrac{2x^2+7}{x^2+2}}{1+\dfrac{2x^2+5}{x^2+1}\dfrac{2x^2+7}{x^2+2}}\right)=$$

$$=\arctan \left(\frac{3}{5x^4+27x^2+37}\right)$$

therefore

$$x^4\left(\arctan\dfrac{2x^2+5}{x^2+1}-\arctan\dfrac{2x^2+7}{x^2+2}\right)=\frac{\arctan \left(\frac{3}{5x^4+27x^2+37}\right)}{\frac{3}{5x^4+27x^2+37}}\frac{3x^4}{5x^4+27x^2+37}\to \frac35$$

Comment: The first equality depends on the fact:$$\arctan\dfrac{2x^2+5}{x^2+1}-\arctan\dfrac{2x^2+7}{x^2+2} \in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right),$$ but which is obvious?

Comment: @mengdie1982 The equality holds since $\dfrac{2x^2+5}{x^2+1}\dfrac{2x^2+7}{x^2+2}\neq 1$ and by definition of $arctan$ function it is returned in the interval $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ which is consistent since the difference tends to $0$. The trick allow us to know how the difference is going to zero without using Taylor's expansion.

Comment: @mengdie1982 Also your method is very fine. Here we can set $$ \frac{2x^2+7}{x^2+2}\le \xi \le \frac{2x^2+5}{x^2+1}$$ since $\frac{2x^2+5}{x^2+1}\ge  \frac{2x^2+7}{x^2+2}$.

Comment: yes, you're right! @gimusi

Comment: Simple and effective approach +1

Comment: You may first substitute $x^2=t$. This reduces typing effort and visual complexity.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks! I prefer to let according the original form but of course you are right use $x^2=y$ or also $x^2+1=y$ would simplify the visualization.

Answer (score 1):

When $x\to \infty$, 
$$\frac{2x^2+5}{x^2+1}=2+\underbrace{\frac{3}{x^2+1}}_{\to 0},\qquad \frac{2x^2+7}{x^2+2}=2+\underbrace{\frac{3}{x^2+2}}_{\to0},$$
and the Taylor approximation of $\arctan(2+t)$ around $0$ is given by
\begin{align*}
\arctan(2+t)=\arctan 2+(\arctan(t+2))'|_{t=0}t+o(t)=\arctan 2+\frac t5+o(t).
\end{align*}
Set $t=\dfrac{3}{x^2+1}$ and $t=\dfrac{3}{x^2+2}$, we have $o(t)=o(x^{-2})$ and
\begin{align*}
\arctan\frac{2x^2+5}{x^2+1}-\arctan\frac{2x^2+7}{x^2+2}&=\frac 35\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}-\frac{1}{x^2+2}\right)}_{:=g(x)}+o(x^{-2}).\\
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
L=\frac35\underbrace{\lim_{x\to\infty}x^4g(x)}_{=1}+\underbrace{\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{o(x^{-2})}{x^{-4}}}_{=\lim\limits_{t\to0}\frac{o(t)}{t^2}=0}=\frac35.
\end{align*}